# MySQL: Insert datetime into other datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, insert

I have a table with a DATETIME column.
I would like to SELECT this datetime value and INSERT it into another column.

I did this (note: '2011-12-18 13:17:17' is the value the former SELECT gave me from the DATETIME field):

```
UPDATE products SET former_date=2011-12-18 13:17:17 WHERE id=1
```

and get

```
    1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '13:17:17 WHERE itemid=1' at line 1
```

Ok, I understand it's wrong to put an unquoted string in there, but is DATETIME just a string in the first place?
What *do* I put in there? 
All I want is reliably transfer the existing value over to a new datetime field...

**EDIT:**

The reason I ask is: I have this special definition, DATETIME, and somehow I thought it gives me some security and other advantages when handling dates. Now it seems it is simply a specialized VARCHAR, so to speak.

Thanks for your answers, it seems this is indeed the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

According to MySQL documentation, you should be able to just enclose that datetime string in single quotes, ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') and it should work. Look here: [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

So, in your case, the command should be as follows:

```
UPDATE products SET former_date='2011-12-18 13:17:17' WHERE id=1
```

Comment: Works, thanks. I guess I think too much in objects when it comes to relational databases...

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
    UPDATE products SET former_date=20111218131717 WHERE id=1
```

Alternatively, you might want to look at using the STR_TO_DATE (see [STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)) function.

Answer (score 8):

for MYSQL try this

> INSERT INTO table1(`myDatetimeField`)VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('12-01-2014 00:00:00','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s');

verification-

> select * from table1
>   
> output- datetime= 2014-12-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the DATETIME value in the rest of your code, it'd be more efficient, simple and secure to use an UPDATE query with a sub-select, something like

```
UPDATE products SET t=(SELECT f FROM products WHERE id=17) WHERE id=42;
```

or in case it's in the same row in a single table, just

```
UPDATE products SET t=f WHERE id=42;
```