# Adding seconds to mysql DateTime via php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to add 12 seconds to a mysql datetime object via php.

My php code generates the following query: "UPDATE Stats SET Usage = 1970-01-01 00:00:12" however the query fails.

My php code is as follows:

```
public function UpdateTime($diffrence)
{
    $seconds = $diffrence / 1000;

    mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass') or die("Unable to select host");

    mysql_select_db('StatDB') or die("Unable to select database");

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM Stats";

    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $retVal = mysql_result($result,0,"Usage");

    $oldTime = new DateTime($retVal);

    $oldTime->modify('+'. $seconds .' seconds');

    $from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($oldTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

    $query2  = "UPDATE Stats SET Usage = $from";
    echo $query2;

    $result2=mysql_query($query2);

    mysql_close();
}
```

Does anyone how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide the error?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage = 1970-01-01 00:00:12' at line 1

Comment: oh, you gotta quote the date with single quotes. `'$from'`

Comment: also, this will update all rows to that time you know.. not just the first row, like you've selected.

Comment: Doesn't work =/ #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage = '1970-01-01 00:00:12'' at line 1

Comment: back tick your table and field names.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$query2  = "UPDATE `Stats` SET `Usage` = '$from'";
```

'Usage' is a reserved word in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to missing quotes in your query. Check out the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551986/2151120).

```
UPDATE Stats SET Usage = '1970-01-01 00:00:12'
```

You should surround the date time value passed in single quotes.

Comment: Nope. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage = '1970-01-01 00:00:12'' at line 1

Comment: You need to change this line: `$query2  = "UPDATE Stats SET Usage = '$from'";`

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of that using one single query:

```
UPDATE Stats SET Usage = Usage + INTERVAL $seconds SECOND
```