# PHP - Changing the datetime to mysql readable datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My date and time string is: `January 28, 2010 1417` with the last four numbers being the time.
How should I go about converting it to a string that would be acceptable by mysql?

when I try using strtotime I get  `Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.`

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$timestamp = strtotime($string);


date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Comment: This messes up the time, but it gets the date correctly. I also get Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.

Comment: @MarlonBrando http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php See here at errors/Exceptions.What`s your php version?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime::createFromFormat($timeString, 'F d, Y Hi')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

(You might need to figure out if your time string uses leading zeroes for the day of the month: "January 05" or "January 5"?)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your programming language, try converting your date/time string to something within single quotes, of this form:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551940/mysql-insert-datetime-into-other-datetime-field) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = new DateTime('January 28, 2010 1417');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

This prints `2010-01-28 14:17:00`